# Issue with UIView size and pushViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have UINavigationController with UIView which have table, text field and button. When user focus on text field I resize UIView for keyboard using following code:

```
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.size.height = 460.f - (up ? 260.f : 44.f);

self.view.frame = viewFrame;
```

After user click on the button I switch to the next view using following code:

```
UserViewController *userViewController = [UserViewController userWithId:((UIButton *)sender).tag];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:userViewController animated:YES];
```

The problem is that when I'm switching to next view the current view which is resized returns back to original size and I don't like how that looks. I want to keep size of UIVIew and keyboard during animation and return it back to default state only after user click back button.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain You UIView Resize Coading in

-(void) ViewWillAppear :(BOOL) animation
{
..coading
}

-(void) ViewWillDisAppear :(BOOL) animation
{

}